# Nav Menu items Underline effect

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to have navigation menu items have underline effect when hovering. This is my current `style.css` code for the navigation menu.

What should I add to make it look something like this? Example: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/54038.html .

This is my current nav bar code.

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu{
display:block !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 14px;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this..

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
  margin: 0;
}
ul { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
li { 
  display: table-cell; 
  position: relative; 
  padding: 15px 0;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y4hc9Lbv/

Comment: Tyvm. Just what I was looking for !

Comment: Hmm actually one thing, After I added the code to style.css THe underline appeared on every link. How do i make it so it appears only on nav bar menu items.

Comment: Specify with a class for example `.navbar-nav`

<ul class="navbar-nav">...</ul>

Should look like this on style.css:
`.navbar-nav ul { // code of ul }`
`.navbar-nav li { // code of li }`
`.navbar-nav a { // code of a }`
`.navbar-nav a:after { // code of a:after }`
`.navbar-nav a:hover:after { // code of a:hover:after }`

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this is the main ul that contains. all the menu items ( one language) which contains all the menu items.

    <ul id="menu-top-nav-main" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li               id="menu-item-601" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type        menu-item-object-page menu-item-601">

so how sohuld it look? )